# Prove that the event '$\lim Y_n$ is finite' is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $Y_1, Y_2, ...$

Tags: probability, random-variable, stochastic-processes, proof

Given random variables $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, ...$, let $\tau = \bigcap_{m\geq1} \sigma(Y_{m+1}, Y_{m+2}, ...)$ be their tail sigma-algebra.

For convenience, $\tau_m \doteq \sigma(Y_{m+1}, Y_{m+2}, ...)$.

$\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$,

$(\lim Y_n < \infty) = (\lim Y_{n+m} < \infty)$

$\to (\lim Y_n < \infty) \in \tau_m \forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ since

$Y_{1+m}, Y_{2+m}, ...$ are RVs on $(\Omega, \tau_m, \mathbb{P})$

If that is right, then we can conclude $(\lim Y_k < \infty) \in \tau$

Is this right?

Comment: Requires only to look at the definition to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of not leaving this unanswered, let us define the event $Y_\infty:= \{\lim_n Y_n <\infty\}$. We want to show that $Y_\infty \in \tau_m$ for any $m$. If we can show this for any $m$ then we are done simply by taking the intersection over $m\geq 1$.

To show this notice that for some $Y$,

$$Y_\infty = \{\lim_n Y_n <\infty\} = \{|Y_i - Y_j|<\epsilon: \forall\;\epsilon>0;\exists\; i,j\geq N_\epsilon\}$$

But then this implies $Y_\infty \in \sigma(Y_{N_\epsilon + 1}, Y_{N_\epsilon + 2}, \dots)=\tau_{N_\epsilon}$ for all $N_\epsilon \geq 1$. Hence, yielding the result.

Comment: thanks Ariel. sooo i'm right?

Comment: Yeah, you certainly can conclude that, to make it rigorous I think using the Cauchy criteria as above is a good idea.

Comment: thanks Ariel! $ \ $